# Why Vercel Web vitals is not loading for my Astro Project?

Tags: vercel, astrojs

[image]I created a landing page using Astro with Tailwind CSS. And it is currently hosted on Vercel. I wanted to try out the analytics service provided by Vercel. I have been able to avail the Audience analytics service provided by Vercel. However, I cannot avail the web vitals services. After enabling the service and redeploying my project, I am stuck in this screen (screen shot provided).

Please note that I did turn off the ad blocker but that did not resolve the issue.I also added the following meta tag to resolve any CSP issue

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' vitals.vercel-insights.com"/>
```

But that has not solved the problem.That is why I want to know does Vercel support analytics for Astro projects and if they do, then what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update, April 2023**

Astro’s Vercel integration added [built-in support for analytics](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/vercel/#analytics) in version 3.1.0. You can now enable this just by updating the Astro config file.

1. If you are not yet using the Vercel adapter, install it in your project:

   ```bash
   npm i @astrojs/vercel
   ```
2. Update `astro.config.mjs` to use the Vercel adapter and set `analytics: true`:

   ```js
   // astro.config.mjs
   import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
   import vercel from '@astrojs/vercel/static';

   export default defineConfig({
     adapter: vercel({
       analytics: true
     }),
   });
   ```

---

**Original answer, December 2022**

Vercel’s Web Vitals analytics currently only has [out-of-the-box support for Next, Nuxt, and Gatsby](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/analytics/quickstart#supported-frameworks).

To track Web Vitals with a different framework like Astro, you need a bit of manual set up work as documented in [Vercel’s Web Vitals API docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/analytics/api).

For example in your base Astro layout you could include a script tag that will import their example code and run it:

```
---
// src/layouts/BaseLayout.astro
---

<script>
import { webVitals } from '../scripts/vitals';

const analyticsId = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_VERCEL_ANALYTICS_ID;

webVitals({
  path: window.location.pathname,
  analyticsId,
});
</script>
```

Here’s Vercel’s example `vitals.js` snippet:

```js
// src/scripts/vitals.js

import { getCLS, getFCP, getFID, getLCP, getTTFB } from 'web-vitals';

const vitalsUrl = 'https://vitals.vercel-analytics.com/v1/vitals';

function getConnectionSpeed() {
  return 'connection' in navigator &&
    navigator['connection'] &&
    'effectiveType' in navigator['connection']
    ? navigator['connection']['effectiveType']
    : '';
}

function sendToAnalytics(metric, options) {
  const body = {
    dsn: options.analyticsId, // qPgJqYH9LQX5o31Ormk8iWhCxZO
    id: metric.id, // v2-1653884975443-1839479248192
    page: options.path, // /blog/my-test
    href: location.href, // https://my-app.vercel.app/blog/my-test
    event_name: metric.name, // TTFB
    value: metric.value.toString(), // 60.20000000298023
    speed: getConnectionSpeed(), // 4g
  };

  if (options.debug) {
    console.log('[Analytics]', metric.name, JSON.stringify(body, null, 2));
  }

  const blob = new Blob([new URLSearchParams(body).toString()], {
    // This content type is necessary for `sendBeacon`
    type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  });
  if (navigator.sendBeacon) {
    navigator.sendBeacon(vitalsUrl, blob);
  } else
    fetch(vitalsUrl, {
      body: blob,
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'omit',
      keepalive: true,
    });
}

export function webVitals(options) {
  try {
    getFID((metric) => sendToAnalytics(metric, options));
    getTTFB((metric) => sendToAnalytics(metric, options));
    getLCP((metric) => sendToAnalytics(metric, options));
    getCLS((metric) => sendToAnalytics(metric, options));
    getFCP((metric) => sendToAnalytics(metric, options));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('[Analytics]', err);
  }
}
```

For a slightly more real-world implementation you, check out the [`<TrackVitals>` Astro component](https://github.com/delucis/astro-badge/blob/5a3e21163f977a4aa163bc528f79d9d2613b8ec9/src/components/TrackVitals.astro) in the `astro-badge` repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately, the solutions did not work for me. Here are the things that I tried.

1) Followed the approach that you have given in the answer in the code snippets.

2) When that did not work, I dived into the IRL example you shared. Followed your implementation of <TrackVitals/> on my project, but still no luck.

3) Finally I cloned your GitHub badges repo, hosted it on vertical, and turned on web Analytics. But I am still getting the same error over there as well. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Hard to say. Could you share your project? If not, do you see any error logging in the browser dev tools when visiting your website?

Comment: After checking the logs I found that the requests to v1/vitals were getting blocked. And after a bit of digging around, I realized one of my content blockers was still on!

I turned it off and it is now working. I followed the track vitals approach. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Vercel analytics has support for frameworks other than Next, Nuxt Gatsby etc. The way to achieve it in Astro (1.6, 2.0 etc.) is to install the `@vercel/analytics` package and inject a simple `<script>` tag that imports it and calls its exported function `inject()`:

```js
<script>
  import { inject } from '@vercel/analytics'
  // @ts-ignore: process.env.NODE_ENV is required by @vercel/analytics internally
  // so that it can determine the correct path for importing the analytics script
  globalThis.process = { env: { NODE_ENV: import.meta.env.MODE } }
  inject()
</script>
```

You can inject this code in your `<head>` section in any `.astro` template file.

Unfortunately, the package is expecting a non-ESM runtime environment and is internally conditionally checking for `process.env.NODE_ENV` to determine which script to load (local-relative path to JS or from a remote host, fully qualified domain name). This is the reason, the MODE needs to be exposed as `process.env.NODE_ENV`. I tried to achieve this via Vite using `define`, but Astro seems to check for `process` somewhere else internally and fails.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Install react and vercel integration using: `npx astro add vercel react`

Then modify the config file like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import vercel from "@astrojs/vercel/serverless"; // can be static or edge instead of serverless

export default defineConfig({
  output: 'server', // not required if using static
  adapter: vercel({
    analytics: true
  })
});
```

Comment: Absolutely! You don’t necessarily need to add React though — just the Vercel integration should be enough.

Comment: not adding react gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this configuration worked well for me.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import vercel from '@astrojs/vercel/static';

export default defineConfig({
  output: "static", // or server
  adapter: vercel({
    webAnalytics: {
      enabled: true,
    }
  }),
});
```

[https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/astro#using-vercel's-features-with-astro](https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/astro#using-vercel%27s-features-with-astro)

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/vercel/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after some research, I found that I am not ignoring the .`vercel` folder once I add it to the `.gitignore` file and push the code to GitHub web vitals worked. Hope this is helpful.